# How to access custom fields of invoices using Zoho Deluge?

Tags: zoho, zohobooks, zoho-deluge

[image: Zoho Screenshot]

I'm trying to access the custom fields of my invoices and I'm getting the following error:
[image: Zoho Error]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To help debug the issue:

- display the values in `invoiceID` and `test2` and make sure they are not empty or zoho numbers (rather than strings)

  ```
  info invoiceID;   
  info test2;
  ```
- Try running the same url in a browser and/or curl to see if the behavior is the same or successful.
- Try putting a 'try/catch' around the invokeurl cmd. Sometimes (but not always) the catch(err) will report more specific error information.

  ```
  try {
      webhooktest = invokeurl
      [
          url: "https:example.org?invoice_id=" + invoiceID + "&tips_ncf=" + test2
      ]
      info "Webhooktest: [" + webhooktest + "]";
  }
  catch(err)
  {
      info err;
  }
  ```